# Solr server could not be reached (Fedora httpd, solr 5, Drupal 8)

Tags: apache, drupal, solr, fedora, selinux

After installing solr 5 with the install_solr_service.sh script, I enabled the service

```
systemctl enable solr
```

But Drupal 8 search_api_solr module is complaining that solr server could not be reached although I can open solr backend interface on localhost in my web browser.

Answer (score 1):

SELinux was blocking services communication on the 8983 port, here is the fix:

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8983
```

Comment: You can verify whether port 8983 is set up via ,`semanage port -l | grep http_port_t`